# Messed up inductor polarities

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

This is a question that has been plaguing me for a long time.
The main problem is assigning polarity across an inductor with its main purpose being its use in Kirchoff's voltage law.

[image]

Now, when I learnt to assign polarity across an inductor, I learnt a small trick.

[image]

So, as per this method, if:
1]The current through an inductor is increasing, the emf will "drop" it through a potential of L(di/dt)or -L(di/dt)

{Pardon my lack of math symbols. I do not know how to use them. Tried to for this post but got lost.}

2]Similarly, if the current through the inductor is decreasing, then the inductor raises the potential by L(di/dt)or +L(di/dt).
Why these plus and minus? I use them so for my KVL equations. For example, with the previous circuit

[image]

And, this worked for all such situations. It was when I got into more complex circuits that it broke down.
For example:

[image]

Now, applying my method for this problem,

1]In loop 1,the switch S1 is closed for a long time. This means that the current through this loop is = e/R. This is because the inductor will behave as a wire after a long time. The polarity across the inductor was found out using my trick. Since connecting the battery would cause an increasing current to flow through the inductor, the potential across it would be dropped by L(di/dt)=
-L(di/dt).

[image]

2]Now,switch S1 is opened and S2 is closed. Since the inductor will not allow instantaneous current change through it, the current will still flow in the same direction through the inductor, top to bottom and decay as per its equation. Since this is a decreasing current, therefore, I mark the new polarity opposite to the initial one.This is because the inductor will raise decreasing current through it up a potential of +L(di/dt) {going from top to bottom. } So, the kvl equation I got from this is

=> +L(di/dt) - 4e - 2R(e/R)=0

Solving for di/dt:

di/dt = 6e/L

Whereas the answer is (-6e/L).

Here is the circuit I used to solve the second part.

[image]

Is there anything wrong in the method I am using? I believe that if I do not flip the voltage polarity in the second step, nothing of this sort would keep happening. But then, I get confused because the current is clearly decreasing and then the inductor wouldn't be doing its job(opposing change in current: for decreasing current throught it, it should oppose this decrease=>help the current=>increase potential in the direction of current flow.)
Kindly help. Also if there are any better(faster and accurate)methods to determine inductor polarities, please do tell.

Comment: Any online resources or links are welcome too.

Answer (score 1):

> The main problem is assigning polarity across an inductor with its main purpose being its use in Kirchoff's voltage law.

Polarity of inductor depends on the phase of oscillation, i.e. it changes with time.

There is no need to "assign polarity" if you only want to apply KVL and write down the equations. Simply define positive direction for each member of the circuit, and then for any conducting path $k$ connecting two nodes, current in that path in the designated positive direction can be denoted as $I_k$.

Drop of electric potential when going from one terminal of the inductor to the other in the designated positive direction is always $L\frac{dI_k}{dt}$. No minuses, no polarities enter into formulating the KVL equation for any closed path.

Comment: I understand. But, can I ask if there is some problem with my understanding that the inductor will change polarity to oppose change in current? Is there some problem with that train of thought? Also, can the method you said be used for capacitors too?

Comment: The opposition to change of current is due to induced emf. Polarity of inductor (location of positive and negative charge on its inductors), on the other hand, is such that electrostatic field due to those separated charges opposes the induced emf. So the polarity is such as if the implied electrostatic field is *causing* the change of current.

Comment: Yes the method is general, drop of potential on a capacitor is $Q/C$, where $Q$ is the charge on the "earlier" capacitor plate in the conducting path, so that $\frac{dQ}{dt} = i$ is the current in the prescribed positive direction in the conducting path where the capacitor is.

Comment: So why does my method work for the first image I posted? Is there something I am missing when solving a complete circuit?

Comment: I don't think it works. KVL says that sum of potential drops in close loop equals zero, and potential drop on inductor in the positive direction is always $Ldi/dt$, so the correct KVL equation is, irrespective of direction of current, $RI+V+Ldi/dt + V_B-V_A = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from @JánLalinský you first need to add some labels.

[image]

A direction arrow with label $i$.
A plus (+) at the node which the current direction is pointing to.
A minus (-) at the other node, A.
A label $v_{\rm L}$.
$v_{\rm L} =L\, di/dt$.

$i$ is the current whose numerical value can be either positive or negative.
If the numerical value of $i$ is positive then the current is flowing in the direction of the arrow and if the numerical value of $i$ is negative then the current is flowing in the opposite direction to the arrow.
$v_{\rm L}$ is the potential of node $B$ which has the plus label relative to the potential of node $A$ which has the minus label.
If the numerical value of $v_{\rm L}$ is positive then node $B$ is at a higher potential than node $A$ and if the numerical value of $v_{\rm L}$ is negative then node $B$ is at a lower potential than node $A$.

This convention takes care of whatever the current direction is and whether the current in increasing with $di/dt$ positive, or the current is decreasing with $di/dt$ negative.

You will note that this is completely in accord to your second diagram.

Now the application of this convention for the first part of you last problem.

[image]
The labelling has been done as per the convention and applying Kirchhoff's voltage law gives $+\mathcal E - iR - L\frac{di}{dt}=0 \Rightarrow i = \frac {\mathcal E}{ R} (1- \exp(-Rt/L))$ if $i=0$ when $t=0$.
So as $t\to \infty$ then $i\to \frac {\mathcal E}{ R} $

Notice that no judgement had to be made about the direction of the current.
If the arrow label had been in the opposite direction and the $+$ and $-$ labels switched the result would have been i = $\large{-}\frac {\mathcal E}{ R} (1- \exp(-Rt/L))$

Now for the second part with $i=\frac {\mathcal E}{ R} $ at $t=0$ as the inductor cannot lose all its energy instantaneously.

[image]

Applying Kirchhoff's voltage law, $v_{\rm L} + v_{\rm R} + 4 \mathcal E =0\Rightarrow L\frac{di}{dt} + \frac {\mathcal E}{ R}\cdot 2R + 4\mathcal E =0\rightarrow \frac{di}{dt} = \large{-} \frac{6\mathcal E}{R}$.
So the current is decreasing which is what one might expect given that the value of the current as $t\to \infty$ is $\large{-}\frac{2\mathcal E}{R}$ - a reversal of direction from that initially.

I suggest that you try this convention out with some of your other examples.